# Is there any way to add more reputation into an existing bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I've made a bounty. But I feel like the question that I've offered the bounty to doesn't have a big enough bounty.

> [What's the best way to start the Crash Landing modpack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182900/whats-the-best-way-to-start-the-crash-landing-modpack)

I mean honestly, who would write a basic walkthrough for 50 reputation?

EDIT: Removed my answer. But the thing is who *would* write a walkthrough (from scratch) for a measley 50 reputation? Could I add more reputation on offer to actually attract **more** attention?

Comment: Why would you put a bounty on a question you are answering yourself?

Comment: I don't want to answer it. I'm starting off with whatever information I have. (I'm hoping for someone else to finish it)

Comment: EDIT: Now regular users can't see my answer. But the point besides is: How do I add more now that my answer is "non-existent"?

Comment: The question Chippies asked isn't really related to your problem. I'm pretty sure you can't modify the value of a bounty in any situation. He was asking, I think, because you appeared to either be attempting to reward your own answer (which doesn't work) or to reward someone else stealing your spotlight (so to speak). Either way, it seemed to contradict the normal incentive structure of bounties.

Comment: In any case, trying to reward someone for "finishing" your answer may not work so well. If they write their own answer that picks up where yours left off, then it won't answer the question completely and may not generally be considered to be a good answer. And you can't reward someone for adding information to your answer with an edit.

Comment: @murgatroid99, now that I have no answer at all (people can't edit or see it, apart from moderators and me), who would write a whole (or half of a) walktrhough for a measly 50 points?

Comment: One, you can edit and undelete your existing answer. Two, when the bounty runs out, you can offer a larger one. Three, maybe you should have thought of that before you offered "a measly 50 points."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a way to add more rep to an existing bounty.

However, I think somewhere along the line you've got a little confused about how bounties work, and what they are for. I say this because you've put a bounty on a post you've already answered at length (a 500 word post!), having deleted your long answer.

While this is not necessarily a bad thing to do in some circumstances (your own answer is outdated and you would like a new answer), I think what you're trying to do is reward someone for extending your answer. That can't work because:

a. You can't award your own bounty to your own post
b. Bounty rep goes to the owner of the post, and not to any editors

While the bounty might encourage another answer to the post, if it was a continuation of your post it would be likely to be merged into it anyway.

It's also worth noting that bounties do not 'buy' answers, they give your post exposure. That is why bounties are never refunded, even if you don't get a satisfactory answer. For your 50 rep, you've bought 50 repsworth of exposure, boosting the posts visibility. Giving a bounty of 500 rep gives you even more visibility, but still no guarantee of an answer.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping if somebody just copy-pasted the whole thing. (And then, when it happens - I delete my post/answer)

Comment: @aytimothy That's just not how this site is designed to work I'm afraid. Duplicate answers will generally be removed.